# Identity Server - Identity/Resource scope - How can client get resource claims about the user

Tags: identityserver3, claims

I have read Dominik's blog post on authentication vs permission modeling using Identity Server (https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/). Since I am mostly using role based authorization, I am fine using IdentityServer as authentication/authorization endpoint for different client and apis.

My question is how to model Identity and Resource scopes properly? Can client know which roles are allowed for the user on specific resource? If yes, can client know only the user roles for requested resources scopes (and not all roles for all scopes).
As far as I understand the concept, if I request claims about the user via *UserInfo* endpoint, I am receiving claims which are filtered by claimTypes listed inside requested identity scopes. That means that if client requests *roles* scope (identity scope with *role* claimtype), *UserInfo* endpoint will respond with all role claims including other applications.

Let's take simple MVC example, where the MVC client communicates with API via REST.
MVC client (client) uses Cookie/OIDC Auth middleware and requests: `ResponseType = "id_token token", Scope = "openid profile api"`.
The API (resource) uses IdentityServerBearerToken Auth middleware and demands: `RequiredScopes = "api"`.
The client has UI elements which should be visible based on *api* role. How can the roles be accessed from client, since the *UserInfo* endpoint will only return identity scope based claims?
Should client ask the API (resource), which actions are possible? And based on the response show/hide UI elements?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

So things are different between IdentityServer3 and IdentityServer4.  My example below is based on IdentityServer4.

You need to do a few of things:

1. define an `IdentityResource` that grants access to the `role` claim.
2. Include that new `IdentityResource` in the client's `AllowedScopes`
3. Have the client request your new `IdentityResource` as a scope.

So what I did was as follows:

Where I defined my resources:

```
new IdentityResource
{
   Name = "roles",
   UserClaims = { JwtClaimType.Role }
}
```

Defined my client as:

```
var client = new Client
{
  // .. other stuff
  AllowedScopes =
  {
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    "roles"
  }
}
```

And then used the the following in my javascript client:

```
new oidc.OidcClient({
  // .. other stuff
  scope: 'openid profile roles'
});
```

I was then able to see all the `JwtClaimType.Role` claims I'd added to the `ClaimPrincipal` in my javascript client.

Comment: Hello,
i try this code but it didn't add the roles to token , but i can add the roles to token if i add it to ApiResource , i don't understand why ???

Comment: You're sure that you've done all the things mentioned?

1) Create new scope, and add Role claim to it
2) Add that new scope to server-side client definition
3) Included that scope in the client-side connection

Answer (score 0):

You can put the roles in your id_token. Implement `GetProfileDataAsync` and add your roles when:

```
context.Caller == Constants.ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderIdentityToken
```

or if you need them on the api you can also add them when:

```
context.Caller == onstants.ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderAccessToken
```

If you make use of `RequestedClaimTypes` passed in the context you can filter out if a certain identity scope is requested or not.

For access tokens the resource scope matters (the claim types you specify on those scopes are put in the `RequestedClaimTypes` for all your requested scopes in the case of

```
context.Caller == Constants.ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderAccessToken)
```

Both are called above if you ask for `id_token token`

The user info endpoint can be called by your `api` in case you use reference access token with `openid` scope (must be called otherwise you don't have any info) or want more claims than by default in the principal (coming from a jwt access token),

```
context.Caller == Constants.ProfileDataCallers.UserInfoEndpoint
```

(here the `RequestedClaimTypes` are the ones specified on the resource scopes your access token has access to..). You can also choose to include them in the `id_token` when the resource scope is part of the requested scopes, for example "`openid myscope`" where myscope is a resource (api for example), by enabling the '`AlwaysIncludeInIdToken`' flag.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it, I needed to add the openid and profile scopes to the client;

```
AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "customAPI.read",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                    }
```